# Number of item count into UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to display some data in the collection view. Data will be coming from the server. I am able to get and show the data in collection view when I gave the number of items as static like `return 20`. Whenever I tried to display data from a server like `return array.count`, that time I am not able to display the data. I just simply got the array of data from the server and added that array to globally declared array, in the number of items section I have given `return globallydeclaredarrayobj.count`. Can anyone helps me, would be great? Thank in advance.

```
//Globally declared variable
 var pro = [[String:Any]]()


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return pro.count
           // return 20
        }

//Data from server 
  var productsdetails = [[String:Any]]()
                    productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "products") as! [[String:Any]]
                    self.pro = productsdetails
                    print("result\(self.pro)")
                    self.collectionview.reloadData()
```

Comment: Please check your array count

Comment: After you receive the data from the server and add it to the array, call reloadData on collectionview.

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows how you are adding the array you got from server to the globally declared array.

Comment: code given above

Comment: usually the problem is the view is getting nil array on didload, try to reload the tableview after getting the array filled. Or maybe your array is empty.
And since this one is collection view, check the flowmanager.

Comment: What is the result of this  `print("result\(self.pro)")` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to print the count before you returning the count in

print(Pro.count)
retrurn Pro.count

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: print(Pro.count): in console printing 0

Comment: From your comment server response object doesn't have any values so only collection view not showing the list...